# SaveBinaryDirect issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, retention

I have a little tool built in CSOM that backs up some pertinent documents by copying them to another site collection (don't ask). Sometimes, the program hangs until I close it as it gets stuck on some files. I'm not sure how to force the program's execution if this process takes too long.

Is there a way to terminate SaveBinaryDirect? Should I check for filesize before calling the method? How can I continue processing if the Save hangs for too long?

```
SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to set a timeout is to use the Task Parallel Library (TPL). You can wrap your call in a `Task` and wait for it to complete based on either a [time span](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) or [cancellation token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321315(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Task upload = Task.Run(() =>
{
    SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
    SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
});

if (!upload.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
{
    // handle upload failure
}
```

Another option is to use a more modern API. `SaveBinaryDirect` was [introduced in 2010 over WebDAV](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/) and has been [superseded with better upload methods](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload). [SharePoint/PnP](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP) recommends using the `ContentStream` property on `FileCreationInformation` (for files less than 10MB) or `StartUpload`, `ContinueUpload`, and `FinishUpload` on the `File` class (for files 10MB or greater).

By using the continuation methods, the app can recover in the middle of a failure in the event of a timeout or cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo for your reference, and you can use this function directly.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// copy a file from a document library in a siteCollection to another document library in another siteCollection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceSiteUrl">http://sp/sites/sourceSite</param>
    /// <param name="destinationSiteUrl">http://sp/sites/destinationSite</param>
    /// <param name="host">http://sp</param>
    /// <param name="sourceListName"></param>
    /// <param name="destinationListName"></param>
    public static void CopyDocFromOneListToAnother(string sourceSiteUrl,string destinationSiteUrl, string host, string sourceListName, string destinationListName, string fileName)
    {
        sourceSiteUrl = sourceSiteUrl.EndsWith("/") ? sourceSiteUrl.Substring(0, sourceSiteUrl.Length - 1) : sourceSiteUrl;
        destinationSiteUrl = destinationSiteUrl.EndsWith("/") ? destinationSiteUrl.Substring(0, destinationSiteUrl.Length - 1) : destinationSiteUrl;
        ClientContext sourceContext = new ClientContext(sourceSiteUrl);
        ClientContext destinationContext = new ClientContext(destinationSiteUrl);
        Web sourceWeb = sourceContext.Site.RootWeb;
        Web destinationWeb = destinationContext.Site.RootWeb;

        List source = sourceWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(sourceListName);
        List destination = destinationWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(destinationListName);
        sourceContext.Load(source);
        destinationContext.Load(destination);
        sourceContext.Load(sourceWeb);
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
        destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();

        FileCollection files = source.RootFolder.Files;
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = files.GetByUrl(sourceSiteUrl+"/"+sourceListName+"/"+fileName);
        sourceContext.Load(file);
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();

            FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(sourceContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            string filePath = host + file.ServerRelativeUrl;
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = fileInfo.Stream;
            FileCreationInformation createFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            byte[] bufferByte = new byte[1024 * 100];
            System.IO.MemoryStream memory = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = fileStream.Read(bufferByte, 0, bufferByte.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memory.Write(bufferByte, 0, len);
            }
            byte[] bytes = memory.GetBuffer();

            createFile.Content = bytes;
            createFile.Url = sourceSiteUrl + "/" + destinationListName + "/" + file.Name;
            createFile.Overwrite = true;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = destination.RootFolder.Files.Add(createFile);
            newFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
            destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();           
    }
```

Comment: This method is limited to 2MB which many of our files will exceed. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint